# Get images from JSON response

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I am developing a shopify theme. Inside my theme. I have a `div` that I am looping. Inside the div, I have an image tag where I want to pass in the image from my JSON file 
**where the div id == to the image id**

In my HTML file, I have this.

```
{% for order in customer.orders %}
{% for line_item in order.line_items %}
<span id="lineNumber">{{ line_item.product_id }}</span>
<div class="order-body">
    <div class="row order-single">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            <img src="" alt="logo" class="fit-image-product" id="imglink">
        </div>
...
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="lg-header">
        <h3>You are not Logged In</h3>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

> In my script file, I have this

```
const lineNumberElements = document.querySelectorAll("#lineNumber");
let arrayOfLineNumbers = [];

for (const key in lineNumberElements) {
  if (lineNumberElements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const element = lineNumberElements[key];
    arrayOfLineNumbers.push(element.innerHTML);
  }
  console.log(arrayOfLineNumbers[key]);
}

const imgsrcElements = document.querySelectorAll("#imglink");
let arrayOfimgSrc = [];

for (const key in imgsrcElements) {
  if (imgsrcElements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const element = imgsrcElements[key];
    arrayOfimgSrc.push(element.innerHTML);
  }
  console.log(arrayOfimgSrc[key]);
}

const geturl = `https://website.myshopify.com//admin/api/2020-04/products.json`;

fetch(geturl, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Shopify-Access-Token": "shppa_###################",
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    //  console.log('resolved', response);
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    let allproducts = data.products;
    console.log(allproducts);
    allproducts.forEach(function (product) {
      let product_id = product.id;
      let product_image = product.image.src;
      //console.log(product_id);
      if (product_id == arrayOfLineNumbers[key]) {
        console.log("how far", product_id, product_image);
        arrayOfimgSrc[key] = product_image;
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("There has been a problem with your operation:", error);
  });
```

I kept getting the error

> There has been a problem with your operation: ReferenceError: key is not defined

### UPDATE

I have been able to minimize my code and error has been removed, but the first image was sent and looped over.

```
    const lineNumberElements = document.querySelectorAll('#lineNumber');
    const imgsrcElements = document.querySelectorAll('#imglink');
    const geturl = `https://beymossweb.myshopify.com//admin/api/2020-04/products.json`
    fetch(geturl, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-Shopify-Access-Token": "shppa_#############",
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            let allproducts = data.products
            console.log(allproducts)
            allproducts.forEach(function (product) {
                let product_id = product.id
                let product_image = product.image.src
                console.log(product_id, product_image);
                for (let j = 0; j <= imgsrcElements.length; j++) {
                    imgsrcElements[j].src = product_image;
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There has been a problem with your operation:', error);
        });
```

Comment: On this line _`if(product_id == arrayOfLineNumbers[key]){`_, `key` is not defined. What do you expect it to be?

Comment: I want to check if the product_id gotten from the response == #lineNumber

Comment: The calls to `querySelectorAll` return a NodeList so you need to work with its results as an array like or use `Array.from` to work with an array. `for in` wont work as you expect in this example

Comment: Remember add `-1` to `imgsrcElements.length` I think it should be `imgsrcElements.length - 1`

Comment: I think you will not achieve the expected result, because for each product you go through the image array and modify its src attribute, I believe that in the end what you would get are all the images with the src attribute of the image of the last product in the list. I think you need an some if

Answer (score 0):

In order to collaborate, it is not a solution to the case you describe but I think it can put us on track to solve it

The methods commented as helpers obtain the text of each `lineNumber` and the value of `src` of each `imglink`, manipulating them as an array, thus solving what I commented regarding `for-in`

Within the successful fetch response I am not clear what you are trying, I understand that in this line `product_id == arrayOfLineNumbers [key]` what you want is to check if there is a value equal to `arrayOfLineNumbers` in the array if that is the case this line will achieve your goal `arrayOfLineNumbers.includes(product_id)`

Finally in this line `arrayOfimgSrc[key] = product_image;` your intention is not clear

1. key does not exist in this context
2. the line tries to assign product_image to an array if it is the case you must use push method

As I mentioned at the beginning this is not intended to be a solution but perhaps by correcting some things and commenting on doubts we can reach the solution

```
// helpers
const toTextContent = (element) => element.textContent;

const toSrc = (element) => element.src;

const nodesToArray = (nodes) => Array.from(nodes);

const getTextContent = (nodes) => nodesToArray(nodes).map(toTextContent);

const getSrc = (nodes) => nodesToArray(nodes).map(toSrc);

// collections
const arrayOfLineNumbers = getTextContent(
  document.querySelectorAll("#lineNumber")
);

const arrayOfimgSrc = getSrc(document.querySelectorAll("#imglink"));

// ajax
const geturl = `https://website.myshopify.com//admin/api/2020-04/products.json`;

fetch(geturl, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Shopify-Access-Token": "shppa_###################",
  },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    data.products.forEach((product) => {
      let product_id = product.id;
      let product_image = product.image.src;

      if (arrayOfLineNumbers.includes(product_id)) {
        console.log("how far", product_id, product_image);
        arrayOfimgSrc[key] = product_image;
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("There has been a problem with your operation:", error);
  });
```

Comment: Can you please check my updated question. I have been able to remove the error, but only the first image is looping. Thanks